# Angular RxJs .share() operator on queryParams

Tags: angular, rxjs, angular-router

I am using a .share() operator on angular router's queryParams Observable.

```
export class App implements OnInit {
    constructor(
        private route: ActivatedRoute,
    ) {}

    ngOnInit() {
        const o$ = this.route.queryParams.share();
        o$.subscribe(console.log);
        o$.subscribe(console.log); // is not called on initialization
    }
}
```

The second subscription is not called initially but gets called after a subsequent route change. How can this behavior be explained?

Comment: It is _kind of_ race condition, but expected behavior. Most likely `queryParams` is a cold observable and subscription triggers emission of the first value immediately. Since the value was emitted when there was just one subscriber it is lost for subsequent subscribers. Still next values are delivered to all subscribed streams. You can change `.share` to `.publishBehavior` to always deliver the last emitted value even if the subscription takes place after last emission happened.

Comment: Why are next values delivered to all subscribed streams? Shouldn't the behavior be consistent?

Comment: Not only next values are delivered to all subscribed streams, but technically the first value as well. In case of the first value, however, there is only one subscriber at the time of emission. The `share`ed stream gets activated upon the first subscription. The next subscribers does not trigger the emission again and `share` operator is memory-less, so the first value is _kind of_ lost.

Comment: Why are you  using share?  What is your goal?